# Elegant way to remove brakets, apostrophe in pandas list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

whats the pandas way to remove the apostrophe, brakets, square brakets from a pandas row with a list?

eg:

```
a       b                 c       d               e      
[178]   [4,7,178,351]  {11,3}  ['T178','S66']  ['4','2']
```

desired output

```
a       b                 c       d        e      
178     4, 7, 178,351    11,3    T178,S66 4,2
```

Comment: Depends on what is actually in your dataframe.  I can't tell from what you've posted (meaning it's ambiguous).  If those are lists and set objects then its `df.applymap(', '.join)`

Comment: @piRSquared Well, I have df like similar way including brakets and apostrophe. When i use df.applymap(', '.join) and i get AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

Comment: So df is a series and not a dataframe. Use apply instead

Comment: @piRSquared it works with string, how do we deal with int or float?

Comment: df.apply(lambda x: ‘, ‘.join(map(str, x)))

Comment: Do you understand what you are doing?  Originally each cell contains a list, which may contain numbers and/or strings.  The desired output will be one string per cell, which `pandas` displays without quotes.  It's a good idea to distinguish between the object (or structure) and how it is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["[178]","[4,7,178,351]","{11,3}","['T178','S66']","['4','2']"]).T
```

The following code solves your problem using `applymap()` and `regex`:

```
import re
df.applymap(lambda s: re.sub(r"[\[\]{}']", '', str(s)))
# output:
     0            1     2         3    4
0  178  4,7,178,351  11,3  T178,S66  4,2
```